# Check if elements or html tags exist

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript tree, where user selects a tree node and clicks on a button which then appends an icon next to that selected tree node.

Here is the source code of one node in that tree:

```
<li node_id="4" name="mars" >
<ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins>
<a href="#" class="jstree-clicked"><ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins> Mars Planet 
    <a style="cursor: default;"><ins class="pattern-icon3"> </ins></a> <!--this line displays the icon-->
    <a style="cursor: default;"><ins class="pattern-icon3"> </ins></a> <!--this line displays the same icon again-->
</a>
</li>
.
.
.
```

Below is the code i use to append the icon next to the tree node.

```
$j("li[name='"+node_name+"'] > a").append('<a style="cursor:default;"><ins class="' + icon_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

The icon is displayed correctly.

**My problem is:**

I need to display a particular icon once only.
Currently, when user selects a node and clicks on the button twice, 2 icons are appended next to that selected node.

Is there a way of checking whether `<a style="cursor: default;"><ins class="pattern-icon3"> </ins></a>` is already appended next to the node name before it is added?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but this use of `<ins>` is not really semantic. If you want a stylized hyphen/minus sign, *use a hyphen*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but am using Jstree to generate the tree from a json file and the <ins> tag is created by the jstree itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try matching the element with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and appending it only if the match failed:

```
var listItemLink = $j("li[name='" + node_name + "'] > a");
if (!listItemLink.find("." + icon_class).length) {
    listItemLink.append('<a style="cursor:default;"><ins class="'
        + icon_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If You want to check that html exists:

```
if ($('#selector').length > 0){
     alert('tag exists');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to select the `.pattern-icon3` element and check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the resulting object. If the element does not exist, `length` will be `0`. If it does exist, it will be greater than `0`:

```
if($j("li[name='" + node_name + "'] > a .pattern-icon3").length) {
    //Already exists!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but maybe you could use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

```
$("li[node_id]").one("click", function () {
    // show the icon
});
```